# What is the fastest way to compare two lists with thounsands of entries?

Tags: python

I have

```
list1 = ["value1;value2;value3;value4;fdsa",]
list2 = ["value1;value2;value3;value4;asdf",]
```

What I need to do is go through each `list2` entry, compare values with index `0,1,2,3` and if they match - use the fourth entry in another method.

Right now I have something like this:

```
for entry1 in list1:
    for entry2 in list2:
        if entry2.split(';')[0] == entry1.split(';')[0]: #... etc, compare first 3 values
            print(entry2.split(';')[4]) # edited out my code
            #do stuff
```

This obviously works, but it is incredibly slow. I am using Python 2.78

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a dictionary from list2's items with first four items as keys and the 5th item as value.

```
dct = dict(x.rsplit(';', 1) for x in list2)
```

And then loop over list1 and check if the key exist in the above dict:

```
for x in list1:
    k, v = x.rsplit(';', 1)
    if k in dct:
       val = dct[k] 
       #do something with val
```

In case `list2` contains repeated keys with different values then you may need to store them in a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in list2:
    k, v  = x.rsplit(';', 1)
    d[k].append(v)

for x in list1:
    k, v  = x.rsplit(';', 1)
    for val in d[k]:
        #do something with val
```

Comment: `{x[:x.rindex(";")]:x[x.rindex(";")+1:] for x in list2}` might be faster

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the entries from list1 multiple times. If you split them once and store the result in a variable, you can reuse it in the inner loop.

Comment: I am not sure if this increased the speed, but if it did it was almost unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0):

For avoiding to split the list2 entries every time for compare with list1 entries store the split list in a separate variable and work with them :

```
>>> l2=map(lambda x:x.split(';'),list2)
>>> [j[4] for i in list1 for j in l2 if i.split(';')[0] == j[0]]
['asdf']
```

Benchmarking :

```
list1 = ["value1;value2;value3;value4;fdsa",]
list2 = ["value1;value2;value3;value4;asdf",]

def test1():    

    l2=map(lambda x:x.split(';'),list2)
    new=[j[4] for i in list1 for j in l2 if i.split(';')[0] == j[0]]


def test2():
    new=[]  
    for entry1 in list1:
        for entry2 in list2:
            if entry2.split(';')[0] == entry1.split(';')[0]: #... etc, compare first 3 values
                 new.append(entry2.split(';')[4]) # edited out my code
                      #do stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print 'test 1 : ',timeit.timeit("test1()", setup="from __main__ import test1")
    print 'test 2 : ',timeit.timeit("test2()", setup="from __main__ import test2")
```

result :

```
test 1 :  1.24494791031
test 2 :  1.34099817276
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
colon_sep_list1=list1.split(";")
colon_sep_list2=list2.split(";")
for index in range(len(colon_sep_list2)):
    if index <=len(colon_sep_list1):
        if colon_sep_list1[index]==colon_sep_list2[index]:
            print colon_sep_list2[4]
            break
```